# NSTextView Text Alignment

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nstextview

well, I was searching for the code to make the "Left/Center/Right" Alignment for the NSTextView. I observe that in Text Menu, this functionality exists, and it is linked to the first responder calling the "alignCenter" selector. However I could not make it to work.

So I start to read the source code of TextEdit. It seems that Apple implement it and shows in the toolbar. However I was not able to find where it is. (It's not in any .nib file, and there's no selector related to align or centre or left, etc..)

So can anyone tell me: how to implement the function exactly like that in the Text Menu.

OR

Where the heck did Apple put the source code of aligning the text in their TextEdit program?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSTextView` inherits from `NSText`, which implements the `alignCenter:`, `alignLeft:` etc. actions.

Comment: yeah! i accidentally found [textView alignRight]; works, just when i put into a switch case structure, it is not. still messing with the code :D

Comment: Probably has to do with your `switch` statement. Maybe forgot a `break`?

Comment: got it. referred to the wrong SegmentedControl to get the index for switch case structure :(

Comment: Note that you must call `insertParagraphSeparator()` if you want the alignment to not be global.

Answer (score -1):

You can use use the alignment property on NSTextView and set the alignment you want (.justified, .center, .left, .natural, etc)

```
let textView = NSTextView()
textView.alignment = .justified
```

or

```
textView.alignment = .center
```